# How to write this statement in mathematical notation?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

No integer bigger than 70 can be expressed as a sum of 3 integers smaller than 30

**My attempt:**
$U_1 = {x∈Z∶x>70 }$
$U_2 = {y∈Z∶y<30 }$
$∄x ∈ U_1 , ∀y ∈ U_2  , x = y_1+y_2+y_3$

I understand that there are many ways to write a sentence in mathematical notations, just wondering whether there is an easier way to write this? Thanks guys :)

Comment: it seems easier to write the contrapositive

Comment: I don't know how you are doing it in your class, but I would avoid using sets. Instead of writing "$x\in U_1$", just write "$x>70$". That said, your attempt is not right. The variables $y_1,y_2,y_3$ should be introduced by some quantifier before they come in play.

Comment: Not everything needs to be in mathematical notation. "No integer bigger than 70 can be expressed as a sum of 3 integers smaller than 30" seems like a perfectly clear and lucid statement to me. It's false (e.g., 25 + 25 + 20) but quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

Just

$$\nexists a,b,c\in\Bbb Z: (a+b+c>70)\land(a,b,c<30)$$

Anyway the statement isn't true, I dont understand why you want to write this.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to try to rewrite your sentence using the expressions "There is", "There is no", "which is",  "which satisfies", etc..., since these are directly translatable to a formal language: "There is=$\exists$", "There is no"=$\not\exists$; For "which satisfies some property", we simply write the property; and so on...

I'd rewrite your expression as: "There is no integer $x$ which is larger than 70 and for which there exist 3 integers, $y_1,y_2,y_3$, which are smaller than 30 and add up to $x$".

So simply applying the first paragraph, we translate it to:

$$\not\exists x\in\mathbb{Z}(x>70 \land(\exists y_1,y_2,y_3\in\mathbb{Z}(y_1<30\land y_2<30\land y_3<30 \land y_1+y_2+y_3=x)))$$

I prefer to use parentheses since they make it  clearer how elements "depend" on each other (in the above, $y_1,y_2$ and $y_3$ "depend" on $x$.

Note, however, that this sentence is false (e.g. $71=29+29+13$).

Comment: if you write it this way, how would you write the contrapositive of this statement?

Comment: @WangJiaLe Contrapositives are defined only for statements of the form $A\rightarrow B$, so it does not really apply in this case since we don't have implications. Another way of writing it would be "Every integer greater than 70 cannot be written as a sum of 3 integers smaller than 30", which translates to $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}(x>70\to(\not\exists y_1,y_2,y_3\in\mathbb{Z}(y_1<30\land y_2<30\land y_3<\30\land y_1+y_2+y_3=x)))$. The contrapositive is "If an integer $x$ can be written as a sum of three integers smaller than 30, then $x\leq 70$". I'll leave the details to you

Comment: (off topic ) The question is, write the statement "no integer larger than 70 can be written as a sum of 3 integers smaller than 30" , when we write it in mathematical notations, does the order matter?

Comment: @WangJiaLe Statements "for all x and for all y" and "for all y and for all x" are equivalent, so the order does not matter in this case. Since the variables ($x,y_1,y_2,y_3$) do not depend on each other in any way, the order in which you bring them does not matter, i.e., we could say the statement is equivalent to "There do not exist integers $y_2,x,y_3,y_1$ such that $x>70$, $y_1,y_2,y_3<30$, and $x=y_1+y_2+y_3$. We are lacking a bit of formality here, so it's a little hard, at least for me, to explain when you can or cannot switch the order in your statement.

Comment: P→Q
∄x∈Z(x>70→(∃y1,y2,y3∈Z(y1<30∧y2<30∧y3<30∧y1+y2+y3=x)))


~Q→~P
∄y1,y2,y3∈Z(y1<30∧y2<30∧y3<\30∧y1+y2+y3=x →∃x∈Z(x>70))